# Некорректная отрисовка текстур в Three.js

Tags: three.js, blender, текстура

при добавлении модели на сцену, некорректно отображается текстура(съехали швы):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот каким должен выглядеть результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам код импорта модели:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/hoff/sofa_section/parma/' );
loader.load( 'parma.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

    scene.add( gltf.scene );
    gltf.scene.receiveShadow = true;


} );
```

P.s. у меня имеется две ноды UV и две mapping, Three.js использует только верхнюю*[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чего-то особой разницы между картинками незаметно .. Есть более наглядный пример? Лучше всего, со стандартными кубиками/текстурами нормалей.

Comment: @Kromster швы съехали, заместо того, чтобы находиться на стыках, они разбросались по разным местам

Comment: А при чем тут нормали, если у вас просто текстура поехала?

Comment: @Kromster на момент публикации вопроса у меня не было догадок, с чем это может быть связано, сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Comment: Замените текстуру на тестовую (легко гуглится), и посмотрите что у вас не так. Кверх-ногами отразилась, или UV не подтянулись, или еще что ..

Comment: @Kromster в консоли выдаёт вот это вот: THREE.GLTFLoader: Custom UV set 1 for texture normalMap not yet supported.